# User defined boost lib in netbeans c++ projects?

Tags: boost, boost-build

I am using boost for my project. I have a user account(**no sudo permission**) with boost 1.41 and my project needs boost 1.53 at least, so I want to use the custom boost-build directory for compiling my program. I have successfully built the boost on my system. But I do not know how to link them with my executable. I am using Jamfiles for code compilation.

I have already done it successfully  with individual files. For example.

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Boost version: " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile and run it with command:

```
[user@server ~]$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp 
[user@server ~]$ ./a.out 
Boost version: 1_40
```

And If I do it like this:

```
[user@server ~]$ g++ -I boost_1_53_0/  test.cpp -L~/boost/stage/lib
[user@server ~]$ ./a.out 
Boost version: 1_53
```

This means that in the second method I am not using system's boost but my own built boost lib. This is what I want to do with my NB projects using `Jamfile` and `Jamroot` files.

My Jamroot lib targets has fields like:

```
lib boost_system : :
        <link>shared
        <name>boost_system ;

lib boost_thread : :
        <link>shared
        <name>boost_thread ;

lib boost_program_options : :
        <link>shared
        <name>boost_program_options ;

lib boost_iostreams : :
        <link>shared
        <name>boost_iostreams ;
```

I guess I will have to add "path/to/build" to it. But I haven't tried it yet.

My Boost Directory:

```
boost_1_53_0
    ...
    stage/lib/[lib files]
```

build-dir:

```
build-dir/boost/bin.v2/
    config.log
    libs/
```

---

**Update:** Adding search paths for the lib targets did not help

```
lib boost_iostreams : :
            <link>shared
            <search>"path/to/boost"
            <name>boost_iostreams ;
```

Please help me !

Comment: What's your include path set to? That version number comes from a header, that's why `g++ -I boost_1_53_0/  test.cpp` worked. I don't really use bjam, but I gather that you need to set [`<include>`](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/libraries.html) appropriately as well for the lib targets. Or perhaps set it once on the [exe](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/targets.html#bbv2.overview.targets.requirements) target.

Comment: Have you tried checking what version of boost is specified in the environment? ($PATH and $INCLUDE)?